# Magento 2 - Add Size Chart issue

Tags: magento2, php, layout, attributes, configurable-product

I try to add Size Chart block on product view page in Magento 2. I add this code in `catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="sizechart" template="product/view/sizechart.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

and this in the sizechart.phtml

```
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct();
?>
<?php if ($_product->getData('size_chart')): ?>
    <a href="#">Size Chart</a>
       <?php 
       echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId($_product->getAttributeText('size_chart'))->toHtml();?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Everything is okay for the simple products, but when I open a configurable product the size chart block in not displayed anymore.

What is the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following code, this may help you.

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="sizechart" template="product/view/sizechart.phtml" after="-" />
</referenceContainer>
```

Try static-content deploy and cache flush commands.

Comment: is not work, I think there we need to add an if statement to the block